# fetch username and post to channel (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So im trying to get a signup bot running and people can signup by reacting to a message.
And when the signup closes, the bot post the random draw on another channel.
however, when the bot writes the list of the users who signed up, it writes both ID,username, and i cannot for the love of god understand why the ID is being posted as well

Code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'rnc',
description: 'Close the Race Night Signup!',
execute(message, args) {
    
    let numParticipants = 18
    if (args.length > 0) {
        numParticipants = args[0]
    }
    if (rnstart.signupMessage) {
        rnstart.signupMessage.then(message => {
            //Reset signup
            rnstart.signupMessage = null

            const signupFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['✍️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
            };

            let signupReaction = message.reactions.cache.filter(signupFilter).first()
            let users = Array.from(signupReaction.users.cache.entries())

            let drivers = []
            
            //If less people have signed up than the required number of participants, include them all =)
            if (users.length <= numParticipants) {
                drivers = users
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < numParticipants; i++) {
                    //Add a random driver 
                    let randomDriver = users.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length), 1);
                    drivers.push(randomDriver)
                }

                //Add remaining users to reserve list
                let reserves = users
                console.log('reserve list: ')
                console.log(reserves)
            }

            //Send message with the drawn drivers
            console.log('driver list: ')
            console.log(drivers)
            const rnDrivers = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.id == "85144558803125125108")

            let msg = 'driver list:\n'
            for (driver of drivers) {
                msg += driver
                msg += '\n'
            }

            rnDrivers.send(`${msg}`)
            

        })
    } else {
        // sign up is not active
    }
}
```

Result:

```
driver list:
8513795998231523550,@username1
13391544790235235,@username2
```

anyone got an idea on how to fix this, i've been staring at this for hours and im almost out of hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID and mention are both being written because `users` is an array made from `Collection#entries()`. This method, when converted to an array, shows both the key and value of all entries (thus the function name). The key is the user's ID, and the value is the user object (which, when stringified, becomes the user mention).

```js
// `users` structure
[['id', 'user object'], ['id', 'user object'], ...]
```

If you want *only* the user mention, then you simply have to use `Collection#values()` instead.

Comment: When i changed to values in the array, it only shows the ID of the user, and removed the user mention

Comment: after changing the Array to values and editing this bit i managed to get only usernames, thank you for the quick reply, it only took me some time, i think i've lost some IQ after looking at this for too long xD

`
let driver = 'driver list:\n'
                for (var i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {
                    driver += (drivers[i].toString())
                    driver += '\n'
                }
`

Comment: Sorry! Maybe try `Collection#keys()`? It should've worked...